# How to handle DateDiff if one date is blank?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can we handle the case where one date is blank in DateDiff method? Example:

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CType(txt61_2.Text, Date), CType(txt21_2.Text, Date))
```

In above statement fields `txt61_2.Text`or `txt21_2.Text` may be empty then take it has `0`

Please let me know how to manage this?

Comment: Why may one of the two dates be null or empty, and also what are you trying to achieve? You could simply use an If statement to find out if the date is null, and if so, set a min or max date, like @rerun has suggested, but would this be a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default conversion from "" to a datetime so a  InvalidCastException occurs.  There is no way to "handle" this occurrence as it must be defined by your business logic.  Assuming that you are using this in a search field you could do something like this.

```
if(string.isnullorempty(txt21_2.Text))then
   date1 = DateTime.MaxValue;
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at DateTime.TryParse/DateTime.Parse and handling the exceptions thrown in you business logic as rerun says.